# Leaflet hide markers in zoom levels

Tags: leaflet, zooming, marker

Is it possible to hide a marker on leaflet map in some specific zoom level?

I tried:`map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);
function onZoomend(){if(map.getZoom()>11){map.removeLayer(markername);}`

BUT it is not working although it is the case for geometries.

I am not refering to marker cluster.

Comment: Works: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/sej/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks to your code, I realized I missed a simple point out. You are right, it's working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code shows  markers in zoom number equal and greater than 14 and for lesser hides marker from the map

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([35.75, 51.375], 8);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar'}).addTo(mymap);


var marker = L.marker([35.75, 51.375],{
    draggable:true,
    title : 'title',
});/

mymap.on('zoomend' , function (e) {
    var geo = mymap.getCenter();
    console.log(mymap.getZoom());
    if (mymap.getZoom()>14)
    {
        marker.setLatLng(geo);
        marker.addTo(mymap);
    }else {
        marker.remove();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjadgol/6qprq9z9/3/